# Undoing .gitignore effects

Tags: git

We added some file that contained versioning information to the `.gitignore` file, to avoid silly commits.
The file is however still versioned and pulled with the repo every time it is checked out.
Now that we have gone up to another iteration (went from v4.5 to v4.6), I want to 'un-ignore' the file, modify & commit it and eventually ignore it back.

I tried:

1. removing the exclusion from `.gitignore`
2. Step 1 + adding a force 'unignore' rule in `.gitignore` (!version.txt)

But the file consistently stays invisible to git eyes. I've also checked my home directory and there's no global `.gitignore` file there.

Answer (score 1):

Okay you can actually:
1) Remove the file from the repo 'git rm ' & remove the exclusion rule from .gitignore -> commit 
2) Recreate the file you deleted, make your changes, add back to git -> commit
3) Put the exclusion rule back in place -> commit